# What is the difference between the using statement and directive in C#?

Tags: c#

this is basically a tutorial question to ask since am a beginner I would like to what is a difference between the using statement we use at start of our C# code to include assembly and namespaces

like this:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

and when we write inside the code within the method or code.
like this:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
```

is there any difference or they both are same, any guidance would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Surprisingly difficult to find a duplicate for this question.

Comment: The first is the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) allowing you to access types defined in a specific namespace without using the fully qualified names.  The second is the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) allowing you to dispose disposable objects easily.

Comment: Note the `using namespace` is a "using directive" rather than a statement. This makes a difference when you move from being a beginner and are interested in the precise definition (eg. in the language specification).

Comment: @user64: Do they even look like they could be doing the same thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of "using" keyword in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769358/use-of-using-keyword-in-c)

Comment: hmm i didnt meant by the both statements doing the same, i meant is both using statements are same or not..thanks Jeff Mercado

Comment: thanks henk-holterman for the duplicate question link, i couldn't find it!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [first (Using Directive)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is to bring a namespace into scope.

This is for example, so you can write

```
StringBuilder MyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

rather than

```
System.Text.StringBuilder MyStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
```

---

The [second (Using Statement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) one is for correctly using (creating and disposing) an object implementing the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface.

For example:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

Here, the `Font` type implements `IDisposable` because it uses [unmanaged resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) that need to be [correctly disposed of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bwa4xa9.aspx) when we are no-longer using the `Font` instance (`font1`).

Comment: No need to thank, accepting an answer is thanks enough on this site. :)

Comment: `using` is also used to explicitly use a `class` or `interface` when there are more than one `class` or `interface` with the same name on different namespaces. Like `mynamespace.TimeZone` for instance, if you are using the `namespace` the framework's `TimeZone` and also `mynamespace` and you need to use a `TimeZone` object then you have to do `using TimeZone = mynamespace.TimeZone`

Answer (score 2):

`using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))`

This using disposes the adapter object automatically once the control leaves the using block.

This is equivalent to the call

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
adapter.dispose();
```

See official documentation on this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That's not directly equivalent.  More equivalent would be the use of try/finally.

Comment: no, this is equivalent to: try { SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); } finally { adapter.dispose(); }

Comment: And it's `Dispose` with a capital D.

Answer (score 0):

They are about as different as you can get.

The first shows intent to use things within a namespace.

The second takes a reference to a disposable object and ensures it is disposed, no matter what happens (like implementing try/finally)

Answer (score 0):

The first allows you to use types that are not defined in your code (tells the compiler where to find the code it needs to reference.
REF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=VS.100).aspx

The second using makes sure that the memory is released upon the end of the code block, or in the case of an exception.
REF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Please see the links above for detailed documentation on each.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will spend a great deal of time answering what amounts to a Google search but here are a couple of links to get you started.

The [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

To allow the use of types in a namespace so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace use [using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

You may find that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) is a great resource to spend some time browsing.