# How C# handles workload with using statement?

Tags: c#, using-statement

I am currently cleaning up the code for my project and trying to improve its performance. As a part of improvement, I thought of removing unused "using" statements from all files. I would like to figure out if that would indeed improve the performance, so here is my question.

Through the "using" statement, is an external library/resource loaded when **any method from the file is executed** (READ: When file itself is loaded) OR the external library is loaded **only when calling a specific method is actually using this library**?

Comment: When you say "using statement" what you really mean is "using directive".  A using statement is something entirely different.  See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923493/what-is-the-difference-between-the-using-statement-and-directive-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using` statement is purely syntactic sugar; it lets you skip writing the namespace when using types in that namespace.

**It has no effect whatsoever on the compiled IL or runtime performance.**