# How to resolve "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ioexception

I am working on a C# .NET application where I need to read and write files. However, I am encountering the error "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" when trying to access a file that is already opened by another process.

I have tried using the FileStream class with FileMode.Open and FileAccess.ReadWrite, as well as using the using statement to automatically close the file when I'm done with it. However, I'm still getting the same error.

How can I resolve this error and access the file in my C# .NET application? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
even though I cannot share the actual code this is what I am doing basically,

```
using System.IO;

string filePath = "path/to/file.txt";
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.ReadWrite);

// Do some work with the file...

fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: Show relevant code. You're probably not disposing a stream you should be.

Comment: You most likely have forgotten some place where you are not using a `using`-statement.

Comment: If there is really a different process holding a reference to the file as you suggest in the question then that process must release the file or you simply can't access. There is no way around that the "other" process must do something. If there is no other process just yours maybe rephrase the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Hey I updated with the code.

Comment: @JonasH used System.IO isn't that enough? or need any other using?

Comment: @Ralf actually the file does not seem to be used in any other process. I checked with task manager and services. I actually even can update the file with text editor. really confusing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923493/what-is-the-difference-between-the-using-statement-and-directive-in-c#:~:text=The%20first%20is%20the%20using,to%20dispose%20disposable%20objects%20easily.

Comment: using *statement* is different from the using *directive*. The later is for namespaces, and is the one you are using. The former is for disposable objects, and that is missing from your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that it is your own process that holds a handle to the file. This is usually due to forgetting to dispose the stream.

The most reliable way to do this is to use the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement

```
using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

just calling `fileStream.Close();` may not be sufficient since it is possible some exception leaves the stream/file open.