# using on object vs not using it on object c#

Tags: c#, .net

Whats the difference and benifits of "using" in this case.
I will state two simular cases please explain why I should or shoudn't use "using" before my reader in this case.

```
string manyLines = @"This is line one
This is line two
Here is line three
The penultimate line is line four
This is the final, fifth line.";

using var reader = new StringReader(manyLines);
string? item;
do
{
    item = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(item);
} while (item != null);
```

vs

```
string manyLines = @"This is line one
This is line two
Here is line three
The penultimate line is line four
This is the final, fifth line.";

var reader = new StringReader(manyLines);
string? item;
do
{
    item = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(item);
} while (item != null);
```

Comment: This one also may answer your question [Using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check these two previous answers

[What are the uses of "using" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c)

[use of "using" keyword in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769358/use-of-using-keyword-in-c-sharp)

But being brief, it's not a matter of "advantage" its more a need. There are object in .NET that have unmanaged resources (resources outside the CLR, like database connections, sockets, OS syscalls, OS APIs etc) and these resources must be disposed manually, because the Garbage Collector does not know exactly when it should release those resources. So the `using` keyword and block will dispose the object as soon as your execution flow gets out of the scope of the `using` block.

Check also these Microsoft documentation about Unmanaged Resources

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects

Answer (score 1):

`using (thing) { ... }`  is just shorthand (approximately) for `try { ... } finally { thing?.Dispose(); }`, when referring to `IDisposable.Dispose()` (there's also an async twin). Most `IDisposable` types should be actively disposed to (for example) close files, release sockets, etc; for `StringReader`, it really won't matter (the dispose is a no-op), but: might as well do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because "stream" is unmanaged resources, if not used "using", unmanaged resources will always occupy memory.

"using" is a sugar, The IL Code is "Dispose" method that calls"Stream" object.

Of course, you can also call "Dispose" method without "using"; "reader.Dispose()"